# API vs REST API

Tags: rest, api

I recently posted this question:
[Rest API for multiple applications?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/418467/rest-api-for-multiple-applications)

After searching a bit more and reading this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189842/what-is-difference-between-rest-and-api, I want to ask how I should choose between a REST API and a non-REST API?

Why should I prefer one style over the other?

I am asking if there is a general answer, but I will also give a specific example.

I understand that both a REST API and a non-REST API can be use by multiple applications (pc app, android app, web app etc).  If I want to create the back-end that all these apps will share (pc app, android app, web app etc), so that all these apps will exchange information with the back-end and the back-end will store all this information, is there any difference in which style of API I choose?

Even if there is no difference, which one should I choose and why?

Comment: Read Roy Fielding's Thesis.

Comment: See also [How I Explained Rest to my Wife](http://www.looah.com/source/view/2284).

Comment: Hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189842/what-is-difference-between-rest-and-api#:~:text=REST%20basically%20is%20a%20style,with%20HTTP%20requests%20and%20responses.) answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

REST is a type of API. Not all APIs are REST, but all REST services are APIs.

API is a very broad term. Generally it's how one piece of code talks to another. In web development API often refers to the way in which we retrieve information from an online service. The API documentation will give you a list of URLs, query parameters and other information on how to make a request from the API, and inform you what sort of response will be given for each query.

REST is a set of rules/standards/guidelines for how to build a web API. Since there are many ways to do so, having an agreed upon system of structuring an API saves time in making decisions when building one, and saves time in understanding how to use one.

Other popular API paradigms include SOAP and GraphQL.